Equal joint distribution for different conditional-marginal pairs
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow (\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$ be random variables.
Now I know the very frequently used results that
$$\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(A, B) = \int_A \mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(B)d\mathbb{P}_X$$
and also
$$\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(A, B) = \int_B \mathbb{P}_{X|Y=y}(A)d\mathbb{P}_Y.$$
What I am interested in is when, in a more general setting, we can tell if the joint distributions that are constructed like this are equal? I.e., what is it in the structure of the two conditionals and the two marginals from above that make them give rise to the same joint distribution by means of the two above equations?
More precisely: Let $\mu$ be a (regular) conditional distribution, such that $\mu(A,y)$ is a probability measure in $A\in \mathcal{F}$ and a measurable function in $y\in \mathcal{Y}$. Let $\nu$ be a marginal distribution on $\mathcal{X}$. Furthermore, let $\rho$ be a (regular) conditional distribution, such that $\rho(B,x)$ is a probability measure in $B\in \mathcal{G}$ and a measurable function in $x\in \mathcal{X}$ and let $\eta$ be a marginal distribution on $\mathcal{Y}$.
Under what circumstances would the joint distributions
$$\int_B \mu(A, y) d\nu(y)$$
and
$$\int_A \rho(B, x) d\eta(x)$$
be equal?
Maybe a closely related question: If I only have $\int_A \mu(A, y) d\nu(y)$, how can I determine the conditional on $\mathcal{Y}$ and marginal distribution on $\mathcal{X}$ that give the same joint distribution?

You integrate $y$ over $A$, yet $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $y\in \mathcal{Y}$. Something is off.

Thanks for your comment I edited the question

I am not sure what your question is. They are equal iff both measures agree on every set of their (common) sigma algebra. Same with your closely related question: You have a joint distribution, so you can just calculate the conditional distribution wrt to a $B$ and the marginal distribution.

To address the problem of determining when two different constructions of joint distributions are equal, we can use the properties of conditional distributions and marginal distributions. Let's denote the random variables as $X$ and $Y$, and their respective probability spaces as follows:

$(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ is the underlying probability space.
$X: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to (X, \mathcal{F})$ is a random variable with a marginal distribution $P_X$.
$Y: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to (Y, \mathcal{G})$ is a random variable with a marginal distribution $P_Y$.

Joint Distribution from Conditional and Marginal Distributions
The joint distribution $P_{X,Y}$ can be constructed in two ways:

Using the conditional distribution $P_{Y|X}$ and the marginal distribution $P_X$: $$P_{X,Y}(A \times B) = \int_A P_{Y|X=x}(B) \, dP_X(x)$$
Using the conditional distribution $P_{X|Y}$ and the marginal distribution $P_Y$:$$P_{X,Y}(A \times B) = \int_B P_{X|Y=y}(A) \, dP_Y(y)$$

Equality of Joint Distributions
For these joint distributions to be equal, the following must hold:$
\int_A P_{Y|X=x}(B) \, dP_X(x) = \int_B P_{X|Y=y}(A) \, dP_Y(y)$
This implies a certain consistency between the conditional distributions and the marginal distributions. The conditions under which these integrals result in the same joint distribution depend on the properties of $P_{Y|X}$ and $P_{X|Y}$.
Specific Conditions

Bayes' Rule: The relationship between $P_{Y|X}$ and $P_{X|Y}$ must adhere to Bayes' rule. Specifically, for all measurable sets $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{G}$:
$$P_{Y|X=x}(B) \cdot dP_X(x) = P_{X|Y=y}(A) \cdot dP_Y(y)$$
This translates into the requirement that:
$$ P_{Y|X=x}(B) = \frac{P_X(x)}{P_Y(y)} P_{X|Y=y}(A)$$
and vice versa.

Consistency: The marginal distributions and conditional distributions must be consistent. This means that integrating the conditional distribution with respect to the marginal distribution should yield the correct joint distribution.

Regularity: The conditional distributions $P_{Y|X}$ and $P_{X|Y}$ must be regular conditional distributions, meaning they should be properly defined for almost every $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, respectively.


Determining the Conditional from the Joint Distribution
Given the joint distribution $P_{X,Y}$, one can find the conditional distribution as follows:

From $P_{X,Y}$ to $P_{Y|X}$:$$P_{Y|X=x}(B) = \frac{P_{X,Y}(dx \times B)}{P_X(dx)}$$
From $P_{X,Y}$ to $P_{X|Y}$:$$P_{X|Y=y}(A) = \frac{P_{X,Y}(A \times dy)}{P_Y(dy)}$$

In summary, the equality of the joint distributions constructed from different conditional-marginal pairs requires consistency and adherence to Bayes' rule. The marginal and conditional distributions must be aligned in such a way that their combination via integration yields the same joint distribution.
